# How do you resize the window size of a tkinter application made using the class method?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hey guys so I am trying to resize my tkinter window using the geometry function if the master window.

I am able to resize it when I tried to do that without creating a class.

But when I tried to resize the window made by the class method I came across a method where the master was resized before passing it as a parameter in the class initialization.

But when I tried to do that without passing the master without passing it as a parameter my interpreter crashes.

What I want to know is what I am doing is it correct?

If not please help me understand why is the interpreter crashing.

Here is the code that I Tried to run.

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.geometry('300x300')
        #self.tk.Tk.geometry('300x300')   Tried this but it didn't do anything.
        Label(text='Post Navigation Button').grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.listbox = Listbox(selectmode='multiple',height=len(x))
        for each_item in range(len(x)):
            self.listbox.insert(END, x[each_item])
            self.listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "lime")
        self.listbox.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.tag = Text(height=1,width=100)
        self.tag.grid(row=0,column=2)
        Button(text='click me',command=self.submit).place(x=500,y=50)
    
    def submit(self):
        text = self.tag.get('0.0',END)
        selection = [self.listbox.get(i) for i in self.listbox.curselection()]
        print(text.strip(),','.join(selection))
        
app = App()
mainloop()
```

I don't want to create a master and pass it as a parameter like this.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
app = App(root)
mainloop()
```

So I just want to know the way to resize the the window from inside the class.

I don't know how correct my code is. So any help is welcome.

Comment: Missing `super().__init__()` at the beginning of `__init__()` of your code using class.  After adding the missing code, it works fine.

Comment: Such a small correction and it worked thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a couple flaws:

1. you need to instanciate the `Tk` class with `super().__init__()` at the very beginning of your init to use its methods and attributes
2. The first arguments for the widgets should be the master, so you need to pass it via `self`
3. You didnt define your list `x`
4. `mainloop` is a function of your object `app`, so call it with `app.mainloop()`

Working example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Listbox, END, Button, Text

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('300x300')
        #self.tk.Tk.geometry('300x300')   Tried this but it didn't do anything.
        Label(self, text='Post Navigation Button').grid(row=0,column=0)
        x = [1,2,3]
        self.listbox = Listbox(self, selectmode='multiple',height=len(x))
        for each_item in range(len(x)):
            self.listbox.insert(END, x[each_item])
            self.listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "lime")
        self.listbox.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.tag = Text(self, height=1,width=100)
        self.tag.grid(row=0,column=2)
        Button(self, text='click me',command=self.submit).place(x=500,y=50)
    
    def submit(self):
        text = self.tag.get('0.0',END)
        selection = [self.listbox.get(i) for i in self.listbox.curselection()]
        print(text.strip(),','.join(selection))
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @mnikley. Yea I didn't share the `x` values as its confidential and the lines after that implied that `x` is a list so the answerer can make x a list of anything just as you did. Thanks again for clearing the correct way write this code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to to resizable **on fly**(when executed). I comment out line 6 and 7. And add this `super().__init__()` in line 5.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Listbox, END, Button, Text

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #self.geometry('300x300')
        #$self.tk.Tk.geometry('300x300')   #Tried this but it didn't do anything.
        Label(text='Post Navigation Button').grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.listbox = Listbox(selectmode='multiple',height=8)
        for each_item in range(5):
            self.listbox.insert(END, each_item)
            self.listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "lime")
        self.listbox.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.tag = Text(height=1,width=100)
        self.tag.grid(row=0,column=2)
        Button(text='click me',command=self.submit).place(x=500,y=80)
    
    def submit(self):
        text = self.tag.get('0.0',END)
        selection = [self.listbox.get(i) for i in self.listbox.curselection()]
        print(text.strip(),','.join(selection))


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The geometry has to be used on the TK() object, not on your class based on it. To do this, you have to get the parent of your class:

```
def __init__(self):
    top=self.winfo_toplevel() #Flexible Toplevel of the window
    top.geometry("300x300")
```

EDIT: There were some more issues with the code that prevented the class from executing properly, including a recursion in the `__init__()` method and a mix of `.grid` and `.place` in your layout. I did not see this when offering a solution for the geometry-problem.

Try this full code here as a starting point:

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):        
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        top=self.winfo_toplevel() #Flexible Toplevel of the window
        top.geometry("300x300")
        self.grid(sticky=N+S+W+E)

        Label(self, text='Post Navigation Button').grid(row=0,column=0)
        x = [1,2,3]
        self.listbox = Listbox(self, selectmode='multiple',height=len(x))
        for each_item in range(len(x)):
            self.listbox.insert(END, x[each_item])
            self.listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "lime")
        self.listbox.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.tag = Text(self, height=1,width=100)
        self.tag.grid(row=0,column=2)
        Button(self, text='click me',command=self.submit).grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)
    
    def submit(self):
        text = self.tag.get('0.0',END)
        selection = [self.listbox.get(i) for i in self.listbox.curselection()]
        print(text.strip(),','.join(selection))

root=Tk()   
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect and your solution has the same issue (`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`) as OP code.

Comment: OP has said that *"I don't want to create a master and pass it as a parameter like this."* in the question.